# Jaeger vs APM tracing performance

Tags: elasticsearch, jaeger, opentracing, apm

I have setup OpenTracing for a microservice solution that uses .Net5. Whent with a full chain:
MicroService -> Jaeger Agent -> Jaeger Collector -> Kafka -> Jaeger Injester -> ElasticSearch -> JaegerUI+Kafka

But lately I found ElasticSearch APM also implements OpenTracing protocol and .Net clients can send traces directly to APM through a shorter stack : MicroService -> APM Server -> ElasticSearch -> Kibana. It looks like this second approach is much simpler and avoids configuration of too much services (collector/kafka/injestors).

I am wondering whether this second solution is as robust in terms of heavy load handling, latency, scalability ... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Was digging through the docs and just start understanding I should switch to OpenTelemetry. ElasticSearch .Net Client library never supported OpenTracing (some languages do though). And as OpenTracing merged into OpenTelemetry it is the way to go in .Net. My question though does not have much sense ...